# How does PostgreSQL decide which query to cancel during deadlock cleanup

Tags: postgresql, locking, deadlock

I know that PostgreSQL will detect and clear deadlock once it happen by cancelling one of the queries. How does PostgreSQL decide which one to cancel? Is this deterministic or there is some randomness in this? Will it cancel the same query always when situation is the same?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the documentation located at http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/explicit-locking.html#LOCKING-DEADLOCKS (*emphasis mine*):

> PostgreSQL automatically detects deadlock situations and resolves them
>   by aborting one of the transactions involved, allowing the other(s) to
>   complete. (*Exactly which transaction will be aborted is difficult to
>   predict and should not be relied upon.*)

Comment: Is there _any_ way to make the user decide?

Comment: @Sotis Structure your code so that you don't have deadlocks!

Comment: I have no idea what cause the deadlock. I have many many node scripts that read or/and write data, and one of those randomly gets a deadlock. It's a long process, rarely executed, so I would like to "protect" it from stopping (if for no other reason I find what stops it!).